# My app crashes each time I push the "submit" button of my input

Tags: android, input, dialog

Every time I try to select the "submit" of my input dialog, my application crashes. Can anyone help me and tell me why it crashes all the time? What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button btnStartDomoos;
private Button btnChangeUrl;
private EditText edi ;
private EditText result;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    showToast();

    btnStartDomoos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);
    btnChangeUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeUrl);
    edi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText) ;
    result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    btnStartDomoos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", edi.getText().toString());

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    btnChangeUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get prompts.xml view
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    // get user input and set it to result
                                    // edit text
                                    result.setText(userInput.getText());
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}

private void showToast(){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Bienvenue dans Domoos ";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}



}
```

Contents of the 'logcat' tab :

```
02-27 19:50:23.023 5506-5506/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-27 19:50:23.578 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup: Parent view is not a TextView
02-27 19:50:23.632 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 15% free 5388K/6268K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
02-27 19:50:23.640 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 8.101MB for 2160016-byte allocation
02-27 19:50:23.664 5506-5515/laurent.ch.domoos D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 7497K/8380K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
02-27 19:50:23.757 5506-5510/laurent.ch.domoos D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 11% free 7499K/8380K, paused 2ms+6ms, total 95ms
02-27 19:50:24.148 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so
02-27 19:50:24.156 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_MRVL.so
02-27 19:50:24.445 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so
02-27 19:50:24.460 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos D/GC: <tid=5506> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver SS_rls_pxa988_JB42_R1_RC2_GC13.15 
02-27 19:50:24.484 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-27 19:50:24.507 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos D/WritingBuddyImpl: getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
02-27 19:50:26.953 5506-5510/laurent.ch.domoos D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 38K, 10% free 8097K/8944K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 35ms
02-27 19:50:27.070 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos D/WritingBuddyImpl: getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
02-27 19:50:29.906 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-27 19:50:29.906 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4167d930)
02-27 19:50:29.906 5506-5506/laurent.ch.domoos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                     at laurent.ch.domoos.MainActivity$2$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:185)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 19:50:31.531 5506-5506/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5506 SIG: 9
```

Comment: could you please post the logcat too..

Comment: we need to take a look at the logcat please..

Comment: THanks for your reply.
I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Now I have edited the question.

Comment: You using wrong id which is not available in xml. Please see my answer.

Comment: what is line number 75 in MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong id in

```
final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput); // use id from xml "prompts"
```

or

```
result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput); // use id from xml "main"
```

`editTextDialogUserInput` should be something else in any one of them. Check your xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem. Have a great day.